# TabCapture API: Resolution increase?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webrtc

I'm messing around with the new `chrome.tabCapture` api, and it seems that the only resolution it currently supports is 640x480. I've tried adding a `videoConstraints` key to the configuration, but it just prevents capturing when it's set to a higher value.

Is there any way to have the `tabCapture` api deliver a full resolution (ie 1920x1080) experience?

EDIT:

It appears my issue was specifying just `height` instead of `maxHeight`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this; and it works:

```
var MediaStreamConstraint = {
    video: true,
    audio: false,
    videoConstraints: {
        mandatory: {
            minWidth: 1920,
            minHeight: 1080,
            maxWidth: 1920,
            maxHeight: 1080
        }
    }
};

chrome.tabCapture.capture(MediaStreamConstraint, function (mediaStream) {});
```

You can set other constraints too like `maxFrameRate` etc.

For a demo; download [tabCapture-and-WebRTC.zip](https://code.google.com/p/muazkh/downloads/list) and change line 41 in the "[tab-capturing.js](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/tabCapture/tab-capturing.js)" file.

Comment: the current doc for chrome.tabCapture doesn't write anything about stopping the sharing. How are you handling this. Why a signalling channel required is a bit unclear

Comment: I'll suggest you try [desktopCapture API](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/desktop-sharing) intead. You simply need to [modify this line](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/blob/master/desktop-sharing/Chrome-Extension/desktop-capturing.js#L60) to use only ["tab"] instead of ["screen","window"]. Desktop-Capture API has a [cancelChooseDesktopMedia](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture#method-cancelChooseDesktopMedia) which allows you leave/stop tab as requested.

Comment: Use stream.stop() to halt the streaming. Note that cancelChooseDesktopMedia does not stop the stream, it simply closes the "choose media" modal (rarely useful, because the user can close it herself).